# JQuery Image Hover before/after

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My first image in DB, I'm using base64_decoding to display image.

My code :

```
$(function(){
$(".image").hover(function(){
    var src = $(this).attr("src");
    $(this).attr("src", "images/add_image.png");
},function(){
    $(this).attr("src", src);
});

});
```

First hover, I created a variable to not losing first image src. But it doesnt work.

Thanks for helping...

Comment: Can you explain about our requirement?

Comment: how can i get first image's src to second function?

Comment: Define a public variable, bring out src and define it before hover function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable isn't accessible in second function, because it lives only in first scope. So you have to make it more global by decalring it before `$.hover()` event.

```
var src = null;
$(".sidebar p img").hover(function(){
    src = $(this).attr("src");
    $(this).attr("src", "images/add_image.png");
},function(){
    $(this).attr("src", src);
})
```